# UWP Frame null reference

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm testing something but.. im stuck in the begining.
I tested many of things, looking in web, but nothing.
In MainPage.xaml:

```
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Frame Name="MainPageMyFrame"></Frame>
    </SplitView.Content>
```

In .cs of MainPage:

```
    private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainPageListView.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MainPageMyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.MainWindow));
        }
    }
```

and every time i'm clicking in item id 0; im getting, and when it want to navigate then :

`Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException'`

MainWindow is UserControl. 
Do anyone have any idea how to fix this error?

@update
MainPage.xaml

```
    <SplitView Grid.Row="1" Name="MainPageSplitView" OpenPaneLength="200" CompactPaneLength="50" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListView Name="MainPageListView" Background="LightGray" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
                <ListView.Items>

                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE806;" FontSize="25" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="15, 0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Rozkład jazdy" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>

                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xEC15;" FontSize="25" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="15, 0" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Komunikaty" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>

                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="MainPageMyFrame" />
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
```

and Here we go, .cs of it:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        MainPageListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void MainPageRelativePanelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPageSplitView.IsPaneOpen = !MainPageSplitView.IsPaneOpen;
    }

    private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if((sender as ListView).SelectedIndex  == 0) // rozklad jazdy
        {
            MainPageMyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.MainWindow)); // from here i want to navigate
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml (Page to where i want to navigate)

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="RozkladJazdy.Pages.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RozkladJazdy.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Name="MainPageStackPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="MainPageTextBlock"/>
            <ProgressRing Name="MainPageProgressRing" IsActive="True" Width="50" Height="50"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

.cs :

```
using RozkladJazdy.Model;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace RozkladJazdy.Pages
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : UserControl
    {
        public static string[,] Lines;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent(); // here the error is thrown
        }
    }
}
```

That's all, Is here something wrong?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking

Comment: Sorry:(

I want to fix that error.
And.. unhappy i don't know how to do it

Comment: I just checked something, and that error is in `Pages.MainWindow` especially in `this.InitalizeComponent()` then crash..

Comment: You need to post all of your code

Comment: I Think it does not matter. Why?
I just created a new blank project. in `MainPage.xam`l added in `Grid ` a `<Frame Name="tests">` and created a new blank `UserControl` `test.xaml`

After `MainPage` loaded, i used:
`tests.Navigate(typeof(test));`
and this same error was throwed.

Comment: It matters because, like everyone else here, I'm not being paid to help you. You're clearly referencing code in your question that isn't listed (clicking a listview) and I'm not here to waste time.

Comment: Nope, dont' worry. Is not because it. Sorry for me.
Look at code above.

Comment: There's way to many things going on here that could be causing the problem. I would recommend creating a demo project and going through this tutorial. http://www.top5solutions.com/page-navigation-uwp-tutorial/ That will help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Youre trying to navigate to a user control instead of a page. Show/hide a usercontrol or create a new page and navigate to that

Comment: If I had to bet on why it was happening though it would be that you are creating a frame in your xaml and trying to use it to navigate between pages. Instead I would use the applications frame

Answer (score 1):

As @Anthony Russell and @SWilko said,
The problem were I wanted to navigate to a UserControl, where i should navigate to a Page.

Before i created a WPF app, so i forgotted that in UWP it should be a Page.

Comment: You cant navigate to a userControl and it can navigate the page and so on.You can do the userControl as a Page.